# Adding 15 minutes interval to a given hour in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a collection with the Open and Close time of a shop like this:

```
  "Monday" => array:2 [▶]
  "Tuesday" => array:2 [▼
    "open_at" => "09:00"
    "close_at" => "18:00"
  ]
  "Wednesday" => array:2 [▶]
  "Thursday" => array:2 [▶]
  "Friday" => array:2 [▶]
  "Saturday" => array:2 [▶]
  "Sonday" => array:2 [▶]
```

I want to add to each day time intervals (appointments) that the shop owners decides. Let's say each 15 minutes. I want to get something like this:

```
"Tuesday" => array:2 [▼
    "open_at" => "09:00"
        2  => "09:15"
        3  => "09:30"
        .... all in between...
        31  => "17:30"
        32  => "17:45"
    "close_at" => "18:00"
]
```

My problem is that the data type is String.
I have tried to parse it with Carbon (I am using Laravel) but I get the error:

```
Trailing Data. Data Missing
```

I have tried to use Pure PHP, but I got surprised that (`strtotime('00:15:00')` is equal to 1576023300 instead of 54000 seconds.

Anyway I continued and did this:

```
if($weekdays[ $index] === 'Tuesday') {
    $open = strtotime($day->open_at);
    $close = strtotime($day->close_at);
    $interval = array();
    // I get 15 minutes in seconds: (strtotime('00:15:00')) == 1576023300 
    for ($i=$open; $i < $close; $i + 1576023300) { 
        $interval[$i] = gmdate("H:i", $i);
    }
};
```

But I do not get it. And this back and forward, together with loops and `if()` function is very error prone.

My questions are:

- Is it correct that (strtotime('00:15:00') is equals to 1576023300 instead 54000 seconds?
- Is there any more clever/magical method of add 15 minutes to a given hour until it reach the end hour?

Comment: 1576023300 =  Wednesday, December 11, 2019 12:15:00 AM check in  https://www.epochconverter.com/ .

Comment: 15 minutes in seconds = 15*60 = 900.

Comment: @Nick. Oh! I was calculating 15 hours (60*60*15)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this resolves your answer to the question :)

```
$str_time = "00:15:00";

$str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $str_time);

sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple implementation (just with 2 days for test purposes). This adds all start times (including `open_at`) to the array with numeric indexes to make it easier to iterate over them:

```
$days = array('Monday'  => array('open_at' => '09:00', 'close_at' => '18:00'),
              'Tuesday' => array('open_at' => '11:00', 'close_at' => '14:00')
);

foreach ($days as &$day) {
    $time = new DateTime($day['open_at']);
    $close = new DateTime($day['close_at']);
    while ($time < $close) {
        $day[] = $time->format('H:i');
        $time->modify('+15 minutes');
    }
}
print_r($days);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [open_at] => 09:00
            [close_at] => 18:00
            [0] => 09:00
            [1] => 09:15
            [2] => 09:30
            [3] => 09:45
            [4] => 10:00
            [5] => 10:15
            [6] => 10:30
            [7] => 10:45
            [8] => 11:00
            [9] => 11:15
            [10] => 11:30
            [11] => 11:45
            [12] => 12:00
            [13] => 12:15
            [14] => 12:30
            [15] => 12:45
            [16] => 13:00
            [17] => 13:15
            [18] => 13:30
            [19] => 13:45
            [20] => 14:00
            [21] => 14:15
            [22] => 14:30
            [23] => 14:45
            [24] => 15:00
            [25] => 15:15
            [26] => 15:30
            [27] => 15:45
            [28] => 16:00
            [29] => 16:15
            [30] => 16:30
            [31] => 16:45
            [32] => 17:00
            [33] => 17:15
            [34] => 17:30
            [35] => 17:45
        )
    [Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [open_at] => 11:00
            [close_at] => 14:00
            [0] => 11:00
            [1] => 11:15
            [2] => 11:30
            [3] => 11:45
            [4] => 12:00
            [5] => 12:15
            [6] => 12:30
            [7] => 12:45
            [8] => 13:00
            [9] => 13:15
            [10] => 13:30
            [11] => 13:45
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/eEUTq)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test this and I tell you the results. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes.

```
if ($weekdays[$index] === 'Tuesday') {
    $tuesday = [
        'open_at' => $day->open_at, // 09:00
        'close_at' => $day->close_at, // 18:00
    ];

    $interval = (new DateTime($day->open_at))->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'))->format('H:i'); // adds 15 mins to 09:00
    $i = 2; //index

    while ($interval < '18:00') {
        $tuesday[$i] = $interval;
        $interval = (new DateTime($interval))->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'))->format('H:i');
        $i++;
    }
};
```

And then finally you can order `$tuesday`:
`asort($tuesday);`.

See working example [here](https://repl.it/repls/ProfuseTallDeprecatedsoftware).